# rxjs/Observable: Running a function once after getting first stream (continuous observable)

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

First off, sorry for the long title.

I am trying to subscribe to an array of continuous streams with [forEach](https://angularfire2.com/api/classes/_utils_firebase_list_observable_.firebaselistobservable.html#foreach) from [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md), but I would also like to run a function after I have confirmed that the first set of data has come in:

```
this.people.forEach((person) => {
    person.items = this.database.list('/items' + person.key);
    person.items.subscribe((data) => {person.itemsList = data});
});

myIntendedFunction();
```

Is there a way to place `myIntendedFunction()` such that:

1. It runs after the first stream of `data` is received for each `person`, and
2. It runs only once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a little more complicated to accomplish if you don't want the first request to happen twice:

```
const connectables: ConnectableObservable<any>[] = [];

this.people.forEach(person => {
    person.items = this.database.list('/items' + person.key);
    const connectable = person.items.publish();
    connectables.push(connectable);
    connectable.subscribe((data) => {person.itemsList = data});
});

Observable.zip(...connectables).take(1).subscribe(myIntendedFunction);

connectables.forEach(c => c.connect());
```

What happens here is this: The effect of `publish()` is basically that you can subscribe to the same stream of data multiple times. Also the subscription function won't be invoked until you call `connect()`. 
If we used `person.items.share()` which is sugar for `person.items.publish().connect()`, it would make the requests right away and our application might be buggy due to race-conditions.

`zip()` waits for every passed observable to emit an item and emits those items all at once as an array. We only want this to happen on the first set of items, so we just `take(1)`.

Comment: This works as I intended (although I'm still figuring out how it works). Thanks! Could I ask what the `...` before `publications` is for, though?

Comment: It's called the 'spread operator'. function(...[a, b, c]) is the same as function(a, b, c), but it works with any number of elements.

Comment: renamed `publications` to `connectables` to better reflect what's happening

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely what you are trying to achieve.
As I understood you are trying to call "myIntendedFunction" after first person is received.
You can subscribe to your observable multiple times (the subscription order matters) and use first() operator to take only first value and then unsubscribe.

```
this.people.subscribe((person) => {
    person.items= this.database.list('/items');
    person.items.subscribe((data) => {person.itemsList = data});
});

this.people.first().subscribe(myIntendedFunction);
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to subscribe to a list of observables (1 per person) and run the function after **all** subscriptions return the first value. I have amended my original post to better reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.first()` operator of `import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'` on firebase list will get the initial values in the list. Without this operator,  your function will be called multiple times and may crash the browser. The  `.toPromise()` operator of 
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'`  will convert the obtained list observable to a promise. You can use `.then()` to use the promise to run your desired function.

```
    this.forEach.person((people) => {
        person.items = this.database.list('/items' + person.key);
        person.items
            .first()
            .toPromise()
            .then(() => {
                myIntendedFunction();
         });
    })
```